# C# ASP.NET Custom Control not showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, ascx

I'm trying to construct a custom control for ASP.NET 
I started by creating a Web Application in VS2010 and creating a new .ascx page. The page is called "TestBox" and it's just a single TextBox control with "This is a test" as the text.

I built the project and then included the DLL in another website in order to make sure I would be able to move controls. Based on a tutorial I found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx) I added the following line of code to the top of the page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="TestControl" Namespace="TestControl" Assembly="TestControl" %>
```

Then I added this to the page itself:

```
<TestControl:TestBox ID="TestBox1" runat="server" />
```

The code compiles and the page loads without throwing up any errors, but when it loads it's completely blank. By introducing a deliberate runtime error, I determined that the TextBox is definitely being loaded, but the control itself still isn't showing up.

Am I missing something?

Code for the TestControl:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestControl.TestBox" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged">This is a test</asp:TextBox>
```

I haven't touched the Designer code or the .cs code in any way.

EDIT: Figured it out. I had declared a namespace for the .CS file but not the .ASPX file itself.

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered HTML to see if there are any clues there?

Comment: Just looked at it and no, there isn't any evidence of the box existing.

Actually, there's this bit:

'<div class="aspNetHidden">'

'<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2NjE1NDk5MTdkZF/UiwtbRgDGFaWAQFsLslFDQfYySq5YfjtmszuryTmx" />'

'</div>'

Comment: That's normal, that's the viewstate for the page.  Can you post the code for your `TestControl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that I had to add a namespace to the ASPX file itself and not just the underlying code file. I forgot to add `Class="TestControl.TestBox"` to the page declaration.